# How to have checkstyle fail on blank lines between annotations and what they're annotating?

Tags: java, checkstyle

I recently received a PR that had a couple field-based annotations separated with blank lines, leaving the annotations looking like they had nowhere to go. I've checked the existing checkstyle rules and searched Google but can't really find anything (and my regex skills are non-existent). So, anyone know how to make sure the annotations are not separated with blank lines?!

Comment: There is no such check (it probably can be done with regexes, but it is error-prone approach), but it sounds like a good idea to have such check. You are welcome to submit feature request https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues